# Fatal error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php on line 82

Tags: magento-1.9

> Fatal error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php on line 82

How to solve this issue? `DOM` extension enabled in cPanel.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please check phpinfo for  php-xml is enabled. Please refer the screenshot below.

[image]

if is not enabled , Please enable in Cpanel.

Comment: its enabled in cpanel but still showing this error

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install the DOM extension.

On Debian / Ubuntu using:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dom
```

And on Centos / Fedora / Red Hat:

```
yum install php-xml
```